# Why can't I use instances of a generic type but can outside?

Tags: java, generics

Consider the following code

```
class SomeClass {
}

class GenericsExample<E extends SomeClass> {

    public void createError() {
        process(new SomeClass()); //Compiler error!
    }

    public void createWorking() {
        E some = new SomeClass(); //Compiler error!
        process(some);
    }

    public void process(E object) {
    }
}

public class Sandbox {
    public void run() {
        new GenericsExample<SomeClass>().process(new SomeClass()); //Not a compiler error?!
        new GenericsExample().process(new SomeClass()); //Still not a compiler error?!
    }
}
```

The message for the first error (the second one is essentially the same thing)

```
required: E
found: SomeClass
reason: actual argument SomeClass cannot be converted to E by method invocation conversion
where E is a type-variable:
  E extends SomeClass declared in class GenericsExample
```

This can be fixed by casting SomeClass to E, but why should I have to? If a method takes E as an argument and E extends SomeClass, shouldn't it accept SomeClass as an argument? Why is this a compiler error instead of a warning?

And why does this not apply to outside classes, even in cases where I don't even declare the generic type? Why are the rules so different in GenericsExample vs Sandbox?

Comment: Try swapping `E extends SomeClass` for `E super SomeClass`. If `E` is a subtype of `SomeClass`, you can't assign an instance of `SomeClass` to type `E` without casting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it will become clear if you just exchange it for a more  specific example.

Assume you swapped `E` and `SomeClass` for `Integer` and `Number` (excuse the extends as opposed to implements) to get `Integer extends Number`.  In this case it's pretty clear that you couldn't do the following

```
Integer i = new Number();
```

as Integer is more specific than Number.

Comment: Why doesn't it fail outside of the class then?

Comment: has nothing to do with being "outside the class". In the other cases, you are just not using a placeholder `E` at all.

Comment: In the first case you defined E as Someclass, so it won't have a compiler error there as it knows that `Someclass` is a `Someclass`. In the second case you didn't specify any Type, so no compiler warning there either.

Answer (score 2):

```
E extends SomeClass
```

As you just wrote, `E` is not the same as `SomeClass`.

You can't assign an instance of a base type to a variable of a more derived type, just like you can't write

```
Button myButton = new Control();  // Not actually a button!
```

The only thing you can assign to a variable of type `E` is an instance of type `E`.

Outside the class, it only works because you're using a `GenericClass<SomeClass>`.  There, `E` *is* `SomeClass`.

Comment: And the raw type `new GenericsExample()` "opts out" of generic type checking.

Comment: ...and gives a compiler warning.

Answer (score 0):

> And why does this not apply to outside classes, even in cases where I don't even declare the generic type?

Because those are different cases:

```
new GenericsExample<SomeClass>().process(new SomeClass());
```

This is not a compiler error, because here, you have `SomeClass` on both sides, *not* `E extends SomeClass`.

```
new GenericsExample().process(new SomeClass());
```

And that is not even using generics, so you are opting out of generic type safety (and get a compiler warning about it).